# Python numpy array indexing rounding error in 4th digit

Tags: python, numpy, rounding

Can someone please explain me the different rounding errors of array in numpy already in the 4th significant digit?

```
dt = 0.001
t = np.arange(-10,10,dt)

print(t)
print(t[-1])
print(t[-1:])
print(t[-1:][0])
print("%.7f" %t[-1])

>> [-10.     -9.999  -9.998 ...   9.997   9.998   9.999]
>> 9.998999999988918
>> [9.999]
>> 9.998999999988918
>> 9.9990000
```

Especially: Why is `t[-1]` not `0.999` ?

Comment: First: you didn't even define `dt` (in your post), so how could we know without guessing and reverse thinking? Second: `t[-1]` is not `0.999` because the limit of your range is 10, not 1. Third: the rest of your question about the "rounding error", which is your main concern afaiu, is simply the fact that computers use a binary number system which is not capable to represent all floating numbers  100% accurate. You'll find a lot about this topic here on SO and in the www, e.g. https://www.floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: Corrected for it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure it is always 9.998999999988918 due to how np.arange is implemented (to be strictly <= the actual goal value). And the difference in your prints comes from how *str* is implemented for

- lists (round to 3 digits after the dot),
- the actual (full) value 9.998999999988918,
- and the decimal function rounding to 7 digits (rounding up from the 8th)

Comment: What do you mean by `to be strictly <= the actual goal value`? That numpy does this on purpose? No, this has nothing to do with implementation of an array initialization function, no matter which library. Believe me, if the numpy devs could get closer to 9.999 here, they would do it, but it's the computer's internal number system which _simply does not allow to get closer_. I'd recommend you to also have a look at https://www.floating-point-gui.de/, just as an example, there are many other sources, too...

Comment: it actually  seems to be a known issue of np.arange  [see here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5808)